# Control-M - .exe works fine in scheduled task

Tags: c#, control-m

I have an old executables wrote in c#.

It works fine in scheduled task, but not under Control-M.

When scheduled as job (job type: OS, a simple command)

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.Console.GetBufferInfo(Boolean
>   throwOnNoConsole, Boolean& succeeded)    at
>   System.Console.get_WindowHeight()    at
>   myprogram.Program.Main(String[] args)

It seems to crash due to an interaction with screen: **get_WindowHeight**

There is a way I can make it works without changing source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely failing because there is no actual console window. Since you can't get the height of a window that doesn't exist (which will throw an exception) then you'll need to either find the source for the original application and re-build it to not require one, or find a way for your automation tool to create an actual console window.